# WebApp with jQuery Mobile on different pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, sybase, sap-bsp

I´m using the jQuery Mobile Framework to develop a Web-Application.

The standard structure is, that all different layouts are in the same html-page.

For example:

```
<div id="home">
        <a href="#one" data-transition="flip">Other Page</a>
</div>
<div id="one">
        <p> Other Layout </p>
</div>
```

But I want to use a number of html-pages for a clearly structure.

The problem is, that a simple href="page2.html" does not work without ah switch on the next page.

Moreover I want to use the webApp in SAP with BSP pages and Sybase. (If that is important for our answers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, and I solved as follow:

```
<div id="home">
    <a href="page2.html" data-transition="flip" data-ajax="false">Other Page</a>
</div>
```

If you add `data-ajax="false"` the browser will load the page as an external page, reloading the page and "skipping" the JQM-behaviour that tries to load the new content inside the `page`.

Hope it helps